# can not find module TypeScript error message?

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, npm

I created a TypeScript's class and published it on `npm`
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/mds.persian.calendar`

I installed it in a Angular project as the following command:
`npm install mds.persian.calendar --save`

It installed successfully, and I can see the mds.persian.calendar folder in `node_modules` folder but when I want to use it in my TypeScript file as the following code, it alert `can not find module`
`import { MdsPersianCalendar } from 'MdsPersianCalendar';`

How should I use it?

Comment: You have to use the correct package name. It is register as `mds.persian.calendar` in npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mds.persian.calendar/package.json this config is missing:

```
{
    ...
    "main": "./mds.persian.calendar.js",
    "types": "./mds.persian.calendar.d.ts"
}
```

That's why you need to reference this module relative e.g. like this

```
//./wwwroot/ts/main.ts

// This doesn't work
//import { MdsPersianCalendar } from 'mds.persian.calendar';

import { MdsPersianCalendar } from '../../node_modules/mds.persian.calendar/mds.persian.calendar';

let calendar = new MdsPersianCalendar();
calendar.now
```

Comment: Have you changed "import { MdsPersianCalendar } from 'MdsPersianCalendar';" to "import { MdsPersianCalendar } from 'mds.persian.calendar';" ?